# Подключение к базе данных несколько проектов laravel

Tags: mysql, база-данных, laravel

У меня есть 2 проекта laravel и они подключаются к одной базе данных. У второго что-то не так с бд. Я конкретно не знаю в чём именно проблема поэтому есть гепотеза о том что mysql не разрешает второму подключиться т.к. подключён уже первый. Мне не нужно исправление данной проблемы мне нужен ответ на этот вопрос. Разрешает ли MySql без включения и прописания чего-то в терминале подключение нескольких проектов?
База данных на 127.0.0.1 имена и пароли идентичные.

Comment: естественно, да.

Comment: *Разрешает ли MySql без включения и прописания чего-то в терминале подключение нескольких проектов?* Самому MySQL пофиг. Он вообще не знает про какие-то там проекты. Учётка есть? пароль правильный? работай...